# how can i find the shortest point for each points in points cloud

Tags: shortest

I have two points dataset, which come from two mesh with an intersection. How can I find the shortest point in the 2nd dateset for each points in the first one?

[image]

Comment: I've never done this, but I think you can use PostgreSQL to load the points and query them: here's [an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/240888) . Setting up PostgreSQL and learning to use it can be a pain, but it's a lot less of a pain then coding your own KD-tree (the tradtitional data structure for spacial work).

Comment: That said, if your data set is small enough, it would be far easier to just compare each point in the first set to each point in the second set. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) has more information

Comment: Thank you very much. the old way of my task is that retrive uniform sample points onto the two meshes.  Now, I have a new idea. I aligned two meshes with ICP（Iterative Closest Point) algorithm. I can get the deformation Matrix after alignment. Then , get the sample points by unifrom sampling of the first mesh, and got the second sample points by  this way: each points of the first samlpe datese multiple the Matrix. I hope it will work.

Comment: You're beyond my depth. Good luck!